# MongoDB not properly serializing my type

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-mvc-4, serialization, f#

I'm trying to implement a custom serialization provider to MongoDB and it works just fine when I'm playing with it in the F# Interactive environment but when I try to port my code to my MVC4 application it won't work and I really can't figure out why it just seems like it's not using the serialization provider. The problem is with the serialization of the discriminated union `Price` which won't work without using the provided custom serialization provider. Anyhow here is the code:

```ml
[<HandleError>]
type AdminController() =
    inherit Controller()
    member x.Index() = x.View()
    member x.CreateProduct() = x.View()
    [<HttpPost>]
    member x.CreateProduct(model) =
        if not x.ModelState.IsValid then x.View(box model) :> ActionResult
        else 
            do DataContext.products.Insert
                ({ Id          = ObjectId(); 
                   Name        = model.Name; 
                   Price       = Regular model.Price
                   Pictures    = model.Pictures; 
                   Description = model.Description
                   Category    = model.Category }) |> ignore
            x.RedirectToAction("Index") :> ActionResult
```

The serialization provider is registered in the `Global.fs` file so it should be called before anything else. I have also tried to decorate the `Price` DU with the `BsonSerializer` attribute but this won't work either.

**Edit**

Well after playing around with this for a bit it turns out the problem wasn't that it wasn't properly serializing my DUs the problem is that it will serialize DUs differently depending on if they are instantiated in FSI or runtime.

For example a DU that looks like this:

```
type DiscriminatedUnion =
| CaseOne
| CaseTwo
```

Will be serialized like this by the BsonSerializer in FSI: `{ "_t" : "CaseOne" }` while in runtime it will be serialized like this:

```
{ "_t" : "CaseOne", 
  "IsCaseOne" : "true", 
  "IsCaseTwo" : "false", 
   "Tag" : 0 
}
```

I'm not sure why but I'm guessing the F# compiler adds extra information to DUs during runtime for interop purposes but that is only a guess..

Anyhow so the problem was really only that I had a mix of BSON-serialized objects from FSI and BSON-serialized objects from the F# compiler.

Comment: Can you show us how you are registering it and the implementation of it?

Comment: Well I managed to solve it, I have added an explanation in an edit in case other people run into this issue.